# Regex to check for only one double-quote

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

If a string as a dot (.) surrounded by double-quotes, then it's valid. Dot on it's own or a single double-quote are invalid.

```
# Valid str examples
str1 = 'Don "B." White'
str10 = 'Don "M.dom" White'
str2 = 'Don "B." White "H." Joe'

# In-valid str examples
str3 = 'Don "B. White'
str4 = 'Don "B." White "H Simpson'
str5 = 'Don B. White' # dot must have double quotes around it e.g. "B."
```

I can check that a dot is surrounded by double quotes using

```
re.search(r'(?!")\.(?!")', str)
```

but struggling a bit to construct reg to detect single double in `str3` or `str4`

I tried different variants of negative lookahead `r'"(?!")'` (i know it's wrong) or `[^"]` regex but can't seem to get it working. Any ideas?

Comment: So how would you detect that `"H Simpson` is invalid?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal - because to allow only double quotes if they are surrounding something containing a dot. `"B."` or `"e.g."` are valid. Hope that makes sense? `"H Simpson` doesn't have a dot followed by closing double quote.

Comment: It looks as though you can get the results be removing valid substrings and then checking for either `"` or `.`: `all(x not in ['.', '"'] for x in re.sub(r'"[^".]*\.[^"]*"', '', str1))`, see ideone.com/6rKYhI

Comment: You'd have to pair the double quotes. Does this do it? `if re.fullmatch(r'(?:[^".]+|"[^"]*\.[^"]*")*', str1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use this regex:

```bash
^(?:[^".\n]*"[^"\n.]*\.[^"\n]*")*[^".\n]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2L26Di/3)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `[^".\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that are not `"` and `.` and not line break
  - `"`: Match a `"`
  - `[^"\n.]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that are not `"` and `.` and not line break
  - `\.`: Match a `.`
  - `[^"\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that are not `"` and not line break
  - `"`: Match a `"`
- `)*`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `[^".\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that are not `"` and not line break
- `$`: End

Comment: Thank you. It looks great but I noticed that it expects dot followed by closing double quote (so wno't match `'Don "Bx.bob" White'`) It's my fault as I didn't put this example in my question above.

Comment: yes, the idea is that a string can't have a dot unless it's enclosed in double quotes.  `"hello.world"`, `"H."`  are valid cases. Dot alone or double quotes alone without dot in between them or an alone double-quote are invalid cases.

Comment: Brilliant! It works well. I will test a few more variations. Thank you!

Comment: Just checking one more thing. `Don B White` is a valid case (no dot, no double quotes). The above regex works fine for it. Is that because of "End non-capture repeat zero or more times"?

Comment: Yes that's right. The ending `[^".\n]*` matches any text that doesn't have `"` or `.`.

Comment: One more point. This regex will match empty string as valid. If you don't want to allow that then use: `^(?!$)(?:[^".\n]*"[^"\n.]*\.[^"\n]*")*[^".\n]*$`

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like that:

```py
re.match(r"""^(?P<string>[^\."\n\r]*(?:(?:"(?:(?!").)+")[^\."\n\r]*)+)$""", my_string)
```

You can see examples in work:

https://regex101.com/r/xgUzEL/1

Also check Unit tests tab.

You may not need external named capturing group `(?P<string>)`, but if you want to use that in part of bigger substring, it may then help.